# Precise Pangolin GRUB error 15

Tags: 12.04

I've installed 12.04 PP on SSD which was the only hard disk plugged to the computer during installation. After installation, rebooted well, system was working smoothly. Then I plugged secondary HDD (containing data, backup etc.) and the system mounted it automatically. 
Then I reboot again and the GRUB was showing error 15 in a boot sequence. Only if I unplug the secondary HDD while rebooting, will make the system to boot normally.
Note that the Ubuntu 12.04 PP is the only OS on the computer. No windows, no dual boot, nothing.
I believe the GRUB need some kind of extra info of a new HDD to make it a part of master boot record. Simply, OS recognize it as a physical address and mounting it well, but it wasn't there during installation process and the GRUB got the problem with it (maybe)

thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second hard drive you plugged in still has some leftover broken bits of grub legacy on it, and your bios is trying to boot that drive instead of the original.  Go into your bios and tell it to boot from the proper drive.

Comment: thx for directions and your answer, made me to act in a different way. Actually there was no grub data on the second hdd cause there was no linux nor win on that hard drive ever. There was some system volume information folder thou which I erased and it allowed me to enter BIOS which wasn't the case in a previous. The problem is fixed and the system boot normaly with both data storages. Thank you mate, you're the man.